# Cannot install IPCV for scilab

Tags: image-processing, scilab

I want to install IPCV for Scilab but I get the error message:

```
-->atomsInstall('IPCV') atomsInstallList: The package IPCV is not available.  !--error 10000 

at line      51 of function atomsError called by :   at line      76
of function atomsInstallList called by :   at line     233 of function
atomsInstall called by :   atomsInstall('IPCV')
```

what is causing the error? what should be done? OS is UBUNTU 14.04.

Comment: what is causing the error? what should be done? OS is UBUNTU 14.04.

Comment: What is your Scilab version ?

Comment: scilab  version  5.5.0

Comment: You need ad least Scilab 6.0, as said in the [IPCV page](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/IPCV/) on the Atoms portal.

Comment: If you want to keep working with that version of Scilab (why ?) you can install [SIVP](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/sivp) instead.

Comment: Thank you  Stéphane, I got it, I have no compulsion of using scilab 5.5.0, I would like to install scilab 6.0, tell me how I get scilab 6.0 installed in ubuntu 14.0? I have tried by sudo apt-get install scilab 6.0 but in the end it is showing  Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Install Scilab 6.0.2 from the tar.gz archive at [https://www.scilab.org/download/6.0.2](https://www.scilab.org/download/6.0.2)

Comment: [here](https://repology.org/project/scilab/versions) you may find all the Scilab versions shipped through different package managers.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane,I have downloaded the scilab-6.0.2.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz file, I have extracted them into a folder  but I am unable to install scilab. Please help.

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet it would be great if you could ship Scilab through cross distro package manager like LinuxBrew, Spack, EasyBuild, AppImage...

Comment: @Foad I have used tar xzvf scilab-6.0.2.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz, but I am still unable to install scilab. Please tell me what to do next?

Comment: first of all you need to archive the `.tar.gz` file. see [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/248780/how-to-compress-and-extract-files-using-the-tar-command-on-linux/) for example. then there is a readme file you should study. as I can see after unarchiving you need to run the `./bin/scilab` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I summarize and complete the comments above, you should

1. download Scilab 6.0.2 at https://www.scilab.org/download/6.0.2 (below I suppose that you took the 32 bits version)
2. extract the archive `scilab-6.0.2.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz` in your home directory (let us consider it as `/home/user543265`)
3. create a text file (e.g. with `gedit`) named `scilab.desktop` with the following content (replace `user543265` by your real user id) and save it in `/home/user543265/Desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=scilab-6.0.2
Icon=scilab
Exec=/home/user543265/scilab-6.0.2/bin/scilab
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Then you should be able to launch Scilab by double-clicking its icon on the Desktop. On the scilab command line you should be able to install IPCV by typing

```
atomsInstall IPCV
```